# LiNQ Compare two datatable

Tags: c#, linq, csv, datatable

This question has been asked before, BUT this specific part has not been.
I have two csv files, 1.csv and 2.csv.

I first covert them both into DataTable
They both have the same schema:

```
1.csv
ID SUBID QTY Value
a  1     55  TEN
a  2     5   FIFTH
b  1     2   TE
```

I need to compare the table above with primary keys {ID, SUBID} mapped with table below with QTY having tolerance of 1 digit off:

```
2.csv
ID SUBID QTY Value
a  1     5  TEN
a  2     6  FIFTH
b  1     2  TEN
```

The output should only be the difference datatable and output of the 2.csv values

```
output.csv
ID SUBID QTY Value
a  1     5  
b  1        TEN
```

Of course this could be done by reading all the values in 1.csv and having a dictionary of {ID, SUBID} -> {QTY, Value} and match that way, but this is a huge list and the time complexity is going to be huge. 
I was wondering if there is a way to do this through LiNQ ie get 1.csv {ID,SUBID} match with 2.csv {ID,SUBID} and traverse through the data table if any mismatch of {QTY - tolerance of over 1 # OR str(Value) difference} put it in a new datatable.

Comment: i did not understand logic of your output also where is QTY in second row and value of first row? (why empty)

Comment: `but this is a huge list`: define huge.

Comment: Apparently not so huge that he can stuff all the data into datatables?

Comment: Huge as in over 3000 rows.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary they are empty because there are no difference we only need to keep track of the difference not the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) to load your csv's into a custom class, then you can do this:

```
var inner=csv1.Join(csv2,
    c1=>new {c1.ID,c1.SUBID},
    c2=>new {c2.ID,c2.SUBID},
    (c1,c2)=>new {c1,c2}).Where(c=>c.c1.Value!=c.c2.Value || Math.Abs(c1.QTY-c2.QTY)>1)
  .Select(c=>new {
    c2.ID,
    c2.SUBID,
    QTY=(c.c1.QTY==c.c2.Value)?null,c.c2.Value,
    Value=c.c1.Value==c.c2.Value?null,c.c2.Value);
```

using [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), you can do this:

```
var left=csv1.ExceptBy(csv2,c=>new {c.ID,c.SUBID})
  .Select(c=>new {c.ID,c.SUBID,QTY=null,Value=null});
var right=csv2.ExceptBy(csv1,c=>new {c.ID,c.SUBID});

var combined=inner.Concat(left).Concat(right);
```

Then use FileHelper to write out your combined result back to a CSV.

If you know that all combinations of ID,SUBID that are in csv1 are in csv2, and all the combinations that are in csv2 are also in csv1, then you don't need the left/right and can just output what is in inner.